# Image Grid like 500px.com or Lightbox. com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-ui

Been trying to implement a similar image grid comparable to that found on the [500px.com](http://500px.com) and [lightbox.com](http://lightbox.com/spotlight) but was unsuccessful.

I was wondering what that grid type is called and if there are any solutions out there to learn/figure out how to create something similar.

Comment: At SO, it's not likely that you will get help without posting some code as this is a site related to coding issues. Please post some code to **1)** help us help you and **2)** Give evidence that you yourself have put effort in to the problem and are not expecting hand outs here.

Answer (score 8):

I think Masonry is what you are looking for, but you have several good jquery plugins.

Check some out here:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most straight-forward jquery gallery of this style is Lightbox2:

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/